# this.state with both variable and object in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How can I add an object and a variable(variable is already defined outside the class) together in **this.state**? If I add only the variable (initialState), it works fine. But when I add an additional object, it does not work.

```
const initialState = {
  input: '',
  imageUrl: '',
  box: {},
  route: 'signin',
  isSignedIn: false,
  user: {
    id: '',
    name: '',
    email: '',
    entries: 0,
    joined: ''
  }
} 

  class App extends Component {
   constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = initialState,
      data: [],
      myList: ''
  }
```

Comment: Why not use class contructor directly like this ?

    class App extends Component {
        constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = initialState,
           data: [],
           myList: '',input: '',
           imageUrl: '',
           box: {},
           route: 'signin',
           isSignedIn: false,
           user: {
             id: '',
             name: '',
             email: '',
             entries: 0,
             joined: ''
           }
     }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`spread operator syntax`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) to add the additional values

```
class App extends Component {
   constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      ...initialState,
      data: [],
      myList: ''
    }
  }
```